# Is this bug for using AngularJS to fetch data to <li><a href> or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I use the AngularJs to fetch the data from mySql database for my navigation bar on HTML5. The problem is I cannot open the link in the sub menu.
Here is my code :

```
<div id="header-wrapper" class="wrapper">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl" id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <h1><a href="index.html">Why Choose a Breeder ?</a></h1>
        <p>Quality Quarantee Knowledge</p>
  </div>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="hollandlop.html">Holland Lops</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="hollandlop.html#buck" id="bucks">Bucks</a></li>
        <li><a href="hollandlop.html#doe" id="does">Does</a></li>
        <li><a href="hollandlop.html#junior" id="juniors">Junior</a></li>

      </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="sale-policy">For Sale</a></li>
      <li><a href="sale-policy">Article</a>
      <ul><li ng-repeat="menu in menues"><a href="{{menu.Link}}" target="_self">{{menu.Title}}</a></li></ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="why-breeder.html#contact" id="contact">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
 </div>
```

[image: Image1]

However I cannot open the link in this code (When I click on link, nothing happens):

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="menu in menues"><a href="{{menu.Link}}" target="_self">{{menu.Title}}</a></li></ul>
```

But If I remove the ul like this :

```
          <li><a href="sale-policy">For Sale</a></li>
          <li><a href="sale-policy">Article</a></li>
          <li ng-repeat="menu in menues"><a href="{{menu.Link}}" target="_self">{{menu.Title}}</a></li>
```

[image: Image2]

I can open the link. I don't know what's wrong. Is it because the order of the navigation bar ? Could you please suggest me, what I'm wrong ?

This is my .js code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.menues = [];
    $http.get("http://www.rhosgobelrabbit.com/getUrl.php")
    .then(function (data) {$scope.menues = data.data.records;
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Error');
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `ng-href` instead of `href`? Also, are you sure it actually opens the correct link in the second instance?

Comment: It is a little unclear what the specific problem is. But you fetch all the links for you navbar from "http://www.rhosgobelrabbit.com/getUrl.php" and then you run a ng-repeat to insert all the markup with the links in. 

But when you say you can't open it, do you mean you can't open the link? If that is the case, then please paste how the url look on the links when they are inserted into the markup.

Comment: I have tried ng-repeat and it doesn't work. I mean when I click to the link and it's noting happen which the link are www.w3school.com and www.rhosgobelrabbit.com/holland-standard. You can try http://www.rhosgobelrabbit.com/why-breeder1. When you click to the sub menu on the Article, nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-href instead of href. You can read about this in the angularJS docs: [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="menu in menues"><a ng-href="{{menu.Link}}" target="_self">{{menu.Title}}</a></li></ul>
```

As long as the ng- aren't placed infront of the href will angular just give you a 404.

Comment: I doesn't get the 404 but when I click to the link, nothing happen. I have already tried ng-href before and I got the same result.